# Query from salesforce in uipath

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath

I am using Connector.Salesforce.Activities in uipath to fetch records.

I am trying to run the following query:

"SELECT id, Name, BillingStreet FROM Account where Name='” + varAccountName+"'"

In the above query, the account name is stored in the `varAccountName` variable.

After executing the query in the Execute SOQL SANDBOX activity, no result is returned. Also, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you get any records if you leave the WHERE condition out of it?

Comment: Yes. If I remove where condition, then all account records are fetched.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your where condition. Try to hardcode it and see what happens.

Comment: Event after hardcoding the value in where condition, no records are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic passing of name is not possible through this connector. You have to look for other options